# issues with waiting for auth to load using firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

The problem I am having is that when the page loads it takes a second to check that the user is logged in.  I use that auth function to create the currentUser variable which I have successfully used in other functions that are triggered by click events.  But when it comes to loading things specific to that user as the page loads, it says the variable is not defined (because it needs auth to complete).

How do you either get the current user before the auth is complete or make the functions that fire on load wait for the auth to be compelete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase released new client libraries last Friday (Oct. 3rd, 2014) which include synchronous accessors for authentication data, which sounds like exactly what you need:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com');
var authData = ref.getAuth();
```

Try upgrading your client library to v1.1.0 or later for the web, and see the latest documentation at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `setInterval`, following code will check `currentUser` every half second and run `fireBusinessLogicHereFunction()` when `currentUser` will be available:

```
var checkAuthInterval = setInterval(function(){
  if ( typeof currentUser !== undefined ) {
      clearInterval(checkAuthInterval);
      fireBusinessLogicHereFunction();
  }
}, 500);
```

Later it will be possible to use `promises` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise